# How to set driver_memory&executor_memory in Pyspark Client mode

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to enlarge driver_memory,I look to offical documents and it said that

> In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file.

So I use pyspark --conf spark.driver.memory=6g --conf spark.executor.memory=6g to change.But after I set and start a test pyfile to check,the configuraiton driver.memory is None.Does anybody know why?Thanks a lot!

Hope to change the setting

Answer (score 1):

Finally I edit '$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf' and add

```
spark.driver.memory 6g
spark.executor.memory 6g
```

to solve.But I still want to figure out why my previous attmept is useless.